# adding badges to user for doing tasks in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Hi Djangonauts,
                How is everyone today, I am new to Django so please forgive any silly mistakes in logic or code. I have a user, a User_Profile and a posts model. I want to give the user badges for the number of posts the user posts. Example if the user posts 3 posts he/she gets a beginner badge and so on...

Below is my **user Profile models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    badge_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)#maybe default can be "static/images/beginner_image.jpg" but it does not work
```

**posts models.py**

```
User = get_user_model()
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)  
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
```

Now I want to achieve something like this:

```
 user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    if user.posts.count >= 3 :
             badge_image = '<img src="some image">'# I don't know how to make a image variable in views and models. I know how to use it in Django templates with {{image.url}}   
    elif user.posts.count >= 20 :
             badge_image = '<img src="some image">'
    else:
         badge_image ='<img src="beginner_image">'
```

Where do I write this code in the models, in the views? I am sorry if my questions are too basic. None of the projects I learned had a similar scenario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it without `ImageField`. Use model's `@property` for this. You need to copy badge images(e.g. `badge_img1.jpg`, `badge_img2.jpg`, etc.) to director with static files(check docs [how to manage static with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)). Rewrite `Profile` like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def badge_image(self):
        if self.user.posts.count() >= 20:
             badge_image = 'badge_img1.jpg'# I don't know how to make a image variable in views and models. I know how to use it in Django templates with {{image.url}}   
        elif self.user.posts.count() >= 3:
             badge_image = 'badge_img2.jpg'
        else:
             badge_image ='badge_img3.jpg'
        return badge_image
```

you can display current user's image like this:

```
{% load static %}
<img src={% static user.profile.badge_image %}>
```

Comment: trying this right now, but it gives me an error, saying `'User' object has no attribute 'post'`  I don't know where to add `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` it usually works if user is defined

Comment: @SamirTendulkar can you add `post` model? If you don't add inside it `related_name='post'` for user's foreign key, then you should do `self.user.post_set.count`. As for your second question, you don't need to add `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` to the view. It's unnecessarily since request already contains information about current user.

Comment: @SamirTendulkar since you have `related_name='posts'` you need to use `self.user.posts.count`. Check updated answer

Comment: I guess that worked but now I'm getting a "TypeError"
 `'>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'`

Comment: @SamirTendulkar ahh, sorry:) It should be `self.user.posts.count()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170909/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-samirtendulkar).